# Casting between similar types in C#

Tags: c#, casting

I have two types that have the same members, but different names. Is there an easy or standard way to cast between them, or do I have to do some serious hacking with reflection?

Comment: Perhaps they should derive from the same base class?

Comment: There's plenty of object to object mappers out there already. Eg, [bltoolkit](http://bltoolkit.net/Doc.ObjectToObject.ashx)

Comment: If you really want to avoid reflexion and have "light" object, you can use [implicit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 9):

You could create an [`interface`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173156.aspx) that describes both of the types. Make each type implement the interface, then use the interface instead of a specific type when working in code that can deal with either type.

Answer (score 7):

You have to either do hacking with reflection (I have a `PropertyCopy` class in [MiscUtil](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/) which can help) *or* use dynamic typing from C# 4.

As far as .NET is concerned, these are *completely* separate types.

Answer (score 1):

This is far from perfect, but I use this extension method to copy properties with the same name between objects based on a common interface

```
public static T CopyTo<T>(this T source, T target) where T : class 
{
    foreach (var propertyInfo in typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public))
    {
        propertyInfo.SetValue(target, propertyInfo.GetValue(source, null), null);
    }

    return target;
}
```

Usage is something like

```
var internationalCustomer = new InternationalCustomer();
var customer = (Customer)internationalCustomer.CopyTo<ICustomer>(new Customer());
```

where InternationalCustomer and Customer both have to have implemented ICustomer.